# Triangle rotate using centroid

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have this centroid $O (.66,-9)$, I need to rotate $45^{\circ}$, how do I do it please?

The full coordinates are $A(2,-9)$, $B(0,-8)$, $C(0, -10)$.
Thanks.

Comment: Rotate it in which direction? Clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: I doubt if this is the centroid of those 3 points. Translate the whole lot so the centroid is at the origin, multiply by the 2 by 2 matrix that represents a rotation ... translate back ... jobs a gooden !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate the coordinate $(x,y)=x+yi$ about the origin  by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians we add or subtract  $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to the argument of $x+yi=re^{i \theta}$.

Now note by Euler's formula,

$$e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$$

By multiplying this complex number by the complex number $x+yi$, we add $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to the argument of $(x,y)$ because $re^{i \theta}e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}=re^{i(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4})}$. Rotating the point $(x,y)$ $45$ degrees counterclockwise.

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i \right)(x+yi)=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(x-y)+i\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(x+y)$$

So the point $(x,y)$ becomes $(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(x-y),\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(x+y))$ after rotation by $45$ degrees counterclockwise about the origin.

Redefine the centroid to be the origin by subtracting $.66$ from every $x$ coordinate and adding $9$ from every $y$ coordinate.

Now rotate everything about the origin (the centroid).

Work:

First we redefine the centroid to be the origin moving all points with it (these are approximations):

$$O (.66,-9) \mapsto (.66-.66,-9+9)=(0,0)$$

$$A (2,-9) \mapsto (2-.66,-9+9)=(1.33,0)$$

$$B (0,-8) \mapsto (0-.66,-8+9)=(-.66,1)$$

$$C (0,-10) \mapsto  (0-.66,-10+9)=(-.66,-1)$$

Now we rotate with formula $(x,y) \mapsto (\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(x-y),\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}(x+y))$,

$$O \mapsto (0,0)$$

$$A \mapsto (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1.33), \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1.33))$$

$$B \mapsto (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1.66), \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(.33))$$

$$C \mapsto (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(.33),\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1.66))$$

Now we undo the translation we did in the first plane by adding $.66$ and subtracting $9$ to the $x$ coordinate and $y$ coordinate respectively.

To get,

$$A'=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1.33)+.66, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1.33)-9)$$

$$B'=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1.66)+.66, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(.33)-9)$$

$$C'=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(.33)+.66,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1.66)-9)$$

Comment: is it rotating the triangle but not moving the centroid? I really didnt understand de formula.

Comment: I will edit it to show work @Gab

Comment: That's impressive, thanks very much. just realised i should be doing it with just clockwise, i used a online calculator and got the result i want, but they dont give you the formula, so from my coordinates                                                  A(5,20)    B(5,−30)  C(15, 25)    the new one rotated 45 degrees are A(2.4, 24 )  B(9.5,31),  C(13, 20), do you know what the formula is?

Comment: For clockwise we have $e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}i}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-i\frac{ \sqrt{2}}{2}$. Upon multiplying this by $x+yi$ and equating it with a point in the complex plane we get $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x+y), \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(y-x))$ so the only difference is that now we use this formula instead .

Comment: That's impressive, thanks very much. just realised i should be doing it with just clockwise, i used a online calculator and got the result i want, but they dont give you the formula, so from my coordinates A(5,20) B(5,−30) C(15, 25) the new one rotated 45 degrees are A(2.4, 24 ) B(9.5,31), C(13, 20), do you know what the formula is?

Comment: You would have to do everything that was done except in the second step you would have to use the formula $(x,y) \mapsto (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x+y), \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(y-x))$ see previous comment.

Comment: The centroid you have is wrong @Gab  Do calculations reconsidering this.

Comment: it's actually A(5,20) B(5,30) C(15, 25) for Centroid (8.33 , 25). I used the wrong one before. I still didn't get it, now I'm confused with what formula to use.

Comment: can you still help me? thanks

Comment: Make a new question @Gab